# Random Windows 10 shutdowns in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, shutdown

I have an Ubuntu host and a Windows 10 guest in VirtualBox.  I never had any trouble until a few weeks ago when it started that the VM shuts down unexpectedly.  This has happened maybe 10 times in a few weeks.  I've been checking Event Viewer, and I always see a log entry that `The previous system shutdown at [some time] was unexpected.`

I ran a Malwarebytes scan which found nothing.  I ran `chkdsk` before booting and it found nothing.  I checked the host's memory (while booted up; it is a remote machine) which found nothing.  I've gotten a few Windows updates since this started.  I'm not experiencing any problems with the host.

What might be causing this problem?

**Update:**
I got another shutdown.  My log has several thousand lines of:

```
25:38:59.216591 VMMDev: vmmDevHeartbeatFlatlinedTimer: Guest seems to be unresponsive. Last heartbeat received 4 seconds ago
25:38:59.274772 VMMDev: GuestHeartBeat: Guest is alive (gone 4 058 509 144 ns)
```

I don't know why I didn't see that in the logs before.

Comment: If you have a VirtualBox VM that ceases to function, then VirtualBox should generate a log, with information with regards to what actually happen.  The logs within the VM are not helpful, as they only contain, the events within the VM and not the host.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I failed to mention that I have looked through the logs in `~/VirtualBox VMs/Windows/Logs` and haven't found anything relevant.  At the moment, the logs have a bunch of startups and shutdowns that I think are intentional.  I'll check again when I get another unexpected shutdown.